# Using Jersey how can I have multiple setters for a field

Tags: java, jersey

So I am using Jersey to deserialize some input sent to an API. Initially, a particular field was a Number value now it's a String value. I was wondering if there was a way to have a multiple setters for that field since I don't want to break people who are already using the API with the old format. Thank you ahead of time.

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MyInput {
  private String clientId;

  public String getClientId() {return clientId;}
  public void setClient(Number clientId) {this.clientId = Long.toString(clientId.longValue());}
  public void setClient(String clientId) {this.clientId = clientId;}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you already have?

Comment: Added what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What library are you using for databinding? Jackson?

Comment: Yes. I am using Jackson.

Comment: In the future, this information is very relevant to your question and would be helpful up front.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that you are using Jackson as your databinding library, you can annotate the setter that you would like Jackson to use (while preserving the old one).

```
public class MyInput {
    private String clientId;

    public String getClientId() {return clientId;}
    public void setClient(Number clientId) {this.clientId = Long.toString(clientId.longValue());}

    @JsonSetter("clientId")
    public void setClient(String clientId) {this.clientId = clientId;}
}
```